# PHP , PDO - Query Results - Vertical to Horizontal

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, pdo

When I do a search based on the below code I get all my results vertically and scrolling down and down ... etc. Is there a way I can get the results to show horizontally for say three boxes then start again below. I am not using a table for the reuslts ,  just styling with CSS. Thanks

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM whisky_results WHERE name LIKE :name ORDER BY name ASC"); // Use = instead of LIKE for full matching
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $search);  
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount(); // Added to count no. of results returned

if ($count >= 1) { // Only displays results if $count is 1 or more

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<div class=\"results\">";
        echo "<div class=\"result_name\">";
            echo "<b>Whisky Name:</b><br>";
            echo $row['name'];
        echo "</div>";

        //echo "<div class= \"result_description\">";
            //echo "Whisky Description:  ";
            //echo $row['description'];
        //echo "</div>";

        echo "<div class= \"result_highprice\">";
            echo "Highest Price Paid: £";
            echo $row['highest_price'];
        echo "</div>";

        echo "<div class= \"result_lowprice\">";
            echo "Lowest Price Paid: £";
            echo $row['lowest_price'];
        echo "</div>";

    echo "<div class= \"average_price\">";
            echo "Average Price Paid: £";
            echo $row['average_price'];
        echo "</div>";

    echo "<div class= \"last_price\">";
            echo "Last Price Paid: £";
            echo $row['last_price'];
        echo "</div>";


    echo "<div class= \"last_date\">";
            echo "Last date sold: ";
            echo $row['last_date'];
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<br>";

} 

} else {
      echo " Sorry no records were found";
}
```

Comment: To be honest I am no further on. Wish someone would explain it in newbie terms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you want to separate your content but this can be done in many ways. Here's one option utilizing `flexbox`.

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  width: 330px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.pod{
  width:30%;
  height:90px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pod">
  
  </div>
  <div class="pod">
  
  </div>
  <div class="pod">
  
  </div>
  <div class="pod">
  
  </div>
  <div class="pod">
  
  </div>
  <div class="pod">
  
  </div>
  <div class="pod">
  
  </div>
  <div class="pod">
  
  </div>
  <div class="pod">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

So, for example:

```
echo "<div class=\"container\">";

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    echo "<div class=\"pod results\">";
        echo "<div class=\"result_name\">";
            echo "<b>Whisky Name:</b><br>";
            echo $row['name'];
        echo "</div>";

        //echo "<div class= \"result_description\">";
            //echo "Whisky Description:  ";
            //echo $row['description'];
        //echo "</div>";

        echo "<div class= \"result_highprice\">";
            echo "Highest Price Paid: £";
            echo $row['highest_price'];
        echo "</div>";

        echo "<div class= \"result_lowprice\">";
            echo "Lowest Price Paid: £";
            echo $row['lowest_price'];
        echo "</div>";

    echo "<div class= \"pod average_price\">";
            echo "Average Price Paid: £";
            echo $row['average_price'];
        echo "</div>";

    echo "<div class= \"pod last_price\">";
            echo "Last Price Paid: £";
            echo $row['last_price'];
            echo "Last date sold: ";
            echo $row['last_date'];
        echo "</div>";

    echo "</div>";

} 

} else {
      echo " Sorry no records were found";
}

echo "</div>";
```

Comment: I don't think that this would work with the actual results I am getting. Its the fact that I am php coding to show all selected results with one snippet of code and I am not sure how to then tell the code the way I want it to show. I am guessing it automatically just shows results as a vertical list. I can style the results box look , but obviously its a generic box for all results. Just not sure how to tell it to show side by side for 3 or 4 rows before going to the next line. But I appreciate the response and please let me know if I am missing something with your response.

Comment: Yeah you didn't understand my example. I'm going to edit my answer to try and help you.

Comment: Thanks Serg , still confused on this one. Appreciate the response.

Comment: I can't make it any more obvious.

Comment: I tried the code and basically it just bring the boxes together , but still one above the other and not horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fetch all the records, then build your view with chunks:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

foreach(array_chunk($rows, 3) as $chunks){
    //<div>
    foreach($chunks as $chunk){
       //print the 3 divs
    }
    //</div>
}
```

Comment: Thans guys. I am still new to PHP PDO etc so this is all really baffeling me. I think I need to do some more reading as to be honest I am a  bit confused. Took me long enough to learn the standard part just to get my results. HTML and CSS i am fine with.

Comment: You should have a separation of concerns, don't mix your queries loop and views

Answer (score 0):

So i posted the question and got some really complicated answers. I would have expected more from this website. You should all "gee yourself a shack" as i have figured it out myself. Next time people try to be a bit more simple and not try to complicate things.

```
   float:left and width ~= 25%
```